# ReactJS: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out why ReactJs is finding "string" instead of my click handler methods.

This is my code:

```
define(["react"], function(React) {


return React.createClass({

    pageUp: function() {
        console.log("go next page");
    },

    pageDown: function() {
        console.log("go prev page");
    },

    toggleMenu: function() {
        console.log("toggle menu");
        this.state.menuStatus = !this.menuStatus;
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            // Toggle menu status; false -> closed | true -> opened
            menuStatus: false
        }
    },

    render: function() {
        var _this = this;
        return (
            <div className="overlay-nav">
                <ul className="up-down-arrows">
                    <li onClick="{this.pageUp}" className="arrow-up"><i className="fa fa-angle-up"></i></li>
                    <li onClick="{_this.pageDown.bind(_this)}" className="arrow-down"><i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i></li>
                </ul>

                <div onClick="{_this.toggleMenu}" className="toggleMenu"><i className="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

});

I already tried to use

```
var _this = _this
// ....
<li onClick="_this.pageUp" ...
```

and binds like

```
<li onClick="{this.pageUp.bind(this)}"
```

But when I refresh the page, I always get this error:

The error I get is:

```
Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got type string(…)
```

Any help is much appreciate.

tks

Comment: You need to remove the quotes. `<li onClick={this.pageUp.bind(this)}>...`

Comment: In vanilla javascript you would probably have onclick="somefunctionname". But not in JSX, yo need to pass a function as stated in the error

Comment: Also, the `.bind(this)` is not necessary if you are using React.createClass, once you have removed the quotes you will probably get a warning stating that is not necessary since React does that for you.

Comment: @nbermudezs you should post that as an answer :)

Comment: @rossipedia I just did. Thanks :)

Comment: Accept the nbermudezs's answer.

Answer (score 87):

You need to remove the quotes. `<li onClick={this.pageUp.bind(this)}>...`

In vanilla javascript you would probably have `onclick="somefunctionname"`. But not in JSX, you need to pass a function as stated in the error.

Also, the `.bind(this)` is not necessary if you are using `React.createClass`. Once you have removed the quotes, you will probably get a warning stating that is not necessary since React does that for you.

Answer (score 34):

I know it is a bit late but still want to answer the questions for others.

Remove `""` after `onClick`.

For example: change `onClick="{this.pageUp}"` to `onClick={this.pageUp}`.

Answer (score 8):

Another scenario this might happen is when you are calling the action method from an onClick event, if you miss the function representation part like...

```
<button onClick = {this.props.increment('INCREMENT')}>+</button>
```

instead

```
<button onClick = {()=>this.props.increment('INCREMENT')}>+</button>
```

the **()=>{}** is important to tell your `onClick` event that it is a function.

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of the parentheses with the function u are using for onClick i.e. onClick = { aFtn() }. This is wrong cause the parentheses directly calls the function on render instead of waiting till the click i.e. onClick.
Solution is just to remove these parentheses like onClick = { aFtn }. 
Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

-> React events are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase.
-> With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

**For example, the HTML:**

```
<button onclick="activateLasers()">
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

**is slightly different in React:**

```
<button onClick={activateLasers}>
  Activate Lasers
</button>
```

**Soure**:- https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
onClick={this.functionName}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using inline functions, try creating arrow functions, assign them to variables, and passing those variable names in between the {} as the onClick handlers. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

***problem cause due to this method***

```js
button onClick ="functionname" // submit button
```

So any one having this error means ----

```js
button onClick={functionname} // submit /button
```

This will resolve your error

Answer (score 0):

try this:  change :

```
<li onClick="{this.pageUp}"
```

to :

```
 <li onClick={()=>pageUp()}
//or
 <li onClick={()=>this.pageUp()}
```